# Slicing is not working in list python

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I am using the following code to create the list and slice it to remove everything but first two

```
",".join((re.findall("'([a-zA-Z0-9,\s]*)'", a['onclick'])[:2])
```

The actual list is

```
Y10765227, 9884877926,9952946340, Dealer, Rgmuthu
L10038779, 9551154555
R10831945, 9150000747
B10750123, 9952946340, Dealer, Bala
R10763559, 9841280752,9551154555, Dealer, Senthil
```

I want just the two elements from the list and should like this

```
Y10765227, 9884877926
L10038779, 9551154555
R10831945, 9150000747
B10750123, 9952946340
R10763559, 9841280752
```

But I am getting all the values.

**urish**'s answer is not working. It is just giving me the first column. I found the reason though. A sample of onclick attribute is here.

```
`onclick="try{appendPropertyPosition(this,'O10956075','9941244412, 9941244413','','Builder','Mr.Bala');jsb9onUnloadTracking();jsevt.stopBubble(event);}catch(e){};"`
```

So if you see the quotes are not for each phone numbers. It is like this

```
'O10956075','9941244412, 9941244413','','Builder','Mr.Bala'
```

I guess I would have to insert the quotes then slice. But I have no clue how to do that

Comment: Can you show us a sample of the data on which you are running `re.findall()` ?

Comment: http://goo.gl/fYGKSj . From this, I just want first two column. This is the output of my script

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to split the list by ',' before slicing it, as following:

```
",".join((re.findall("'([a-zA-Z0-9,\s]*)'", a['onclick'])[0].split(",")[:2]))
```

Comment: I guess I am splitting it already, if you look at my spreadsheet that I have linked in the comment. But let me try this too